# Parse xmltype into table after pivot xml

Tags: sql, oracle, xml-parsing, pivot, xmltable

i have return XMLTYPE after pivot xml that looks like

```
<PivotSet>
<item>
        <column name = "country">Ukraine</column>
        <column name = "population">12345</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "country">Germany</column>
        <column name = "population">67891</column>
    </item>
...
</PivotSet>
```

i need to get table that will look like

```
Ukraine_population|Germany_population|...

12345             |67891             |...
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried xmltable, but i am not sure that i used it correctly, please help;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the country value with this XPath expression:

```
/PivotSet/item/column[@name="country"]
```

And a similar one for the population. Giving:

```
with x as (
  select xmltype ( 
'<PivotSet>
<item>
        <column name = "country">Ukraine</column>
        <column name = "population">12345</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "country">Germany</column>
        <column name = "population">67891</column>
    </item>
</PivotSet>' 
) x from dual
)
select xt.* from x, xmltable (
  '/PivotSet/item'
  passing x.x 
  columns 
    country varchar2(100) 
      path 'column[@name="country"]',
    population int
      path 'column[@name="population"]'
) xt

COUNTRY   POPULATION   
Ukraine        12345         
Germany        67891
```

But if you want a column for each country, from here you still need to `pivot` the data to get the result!

Which begs the question:

Why use an XML pivot?

If it's because you don't know the country names and are doing something like:

```
pivot xml ( 
  min ( population ) 
    for country in ( any ) 
)
```

This hasn't saved you anything! You still need to know the country names to get the output as columns.