# pivot XML parsing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, xmltable, pivot-xml

I have problem exactly like the post:
[Parse xmltype into table after pivot xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422116/parse-xmltype-into-table-after-pivot-xml)

I want to use pivot xml and then parse the xml (maybe with xmltable function) to table.
What can I do if I don't know the countries name and how many countries exist?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to use a dynamic pivot rather than an XML pivot; but this is probably something you should do in a reporting layer.

Comment: Do you have maybe an example?

Comment: [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17576182/266304), and there are many others, but you'll have to adapt to your data and query.

Comment: thanks! honestly i still didn't succuess. I used the example that you sent , added:"SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;" , use sql-developer but nothing is printed on the screen.

Comment: @AlexPoole Do you know maybe?

Comment: That example doesn't use server output. The results are returned via a ref cursor, which is a bind variable - declared with `variable` and displayed with `print`. You need to run as a script, but you'd get prompts or errors if you didn't. I suggest you try to adapt something like that, and if you can't then ask a new question including the code you're using, sample data and expected results (all as formatted text, not images).

Comment: @AlexPoole thank you! works! :) now I need to create new question and ask if it's possible to run that also from excel (through get ODBC data)